# zend http client current url

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect, curl

I am porting a old project written in plain php to zend framework(and I am new to zend), I am using zend http client(with cURL adapter) in zend project to replace the cULR part of old php project. I got stuck-up as I don't know the zend http client alternate for

```
$landing_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
```

which return the url of the landing page after any redirection during the cURL request. I could able to be successfully do the following with zend

```
$config = array(
            'adapter'   => 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl',
            'curloptions' => array(
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER    =>    true,
                    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION    =>    true,
            ),
    );
    $redirecting_page_address ='https://www.domain.tld/someredirectingurl';

    $client = new Zend_Http_Client($redirecting_page_address, $config);

    $response = $client->request();
```

and got the required page as output using `$response->getBody()` now I want to know the url of the landed page where `$redirecting_page_address` redirected to. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Cyril answered for himself, there is no high-level API in zend framework 2 (2.2.8 2014-09-17) to fetch the effective URL. You can, however, fetch the original curl handle and use native PHP functions on it:

```
// $client would be a Zend_Http_Client
$handle = $client->getAdapter()->getHandle();
$effectiveUrl = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
```

Answer (score 0):

If redirect is done by headers, you can use

```
if ($response->isRedirect()){
     $newUrl = $response->getHeader('Location');
}
```

Comment: This didn't helped me as I need the url after the redirection is done, after the redirection Location header is not available. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

In my research over this I found there no way to do this till the current versions of zend framework (2.0.6), maybe in the future versions this facility can be included.